.Net Zero MQ/NET MQ creates new NetMQRuntime() for each request
I am using the Net MQ (Zero MQ) async implementation described in their docs: https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async-await/
I have implemented this on my .aspx page which processes each request and sends to the server. This all works fine but I am aware that I am creating a new runtime for each request - this seems inefficient - is there another way?
Public Shared Async Function HandleRequest

    Dim tcs As New TaskCompletionSource(Of String)()

    Using runtime As New NetMQRuntime()
        runtime.Run(StartAsync(tcs, requestStr))
    End Using

    Dim response As String = Await tcs.Task

End Function

Private Shared Async Function StartAsync()
    'send to server, receive response.
    ..
    ..
    Return response
End Function


Obvious to me alternative is to have a runtime as a higher-level class object.  You'll need IDisposable on its owner which will in turn Dispose the object.
